# How to get the display density in a lightning components controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

Is it possible to see if a user is in Comfy or Compact display density in a lightning controller? This is a new feature since Winter '19 and I cant find any documentation about this.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set/configure the display density for lightning standard components like lightning:recordForm? A user's styling configuration for Comfy/Compact doesn't appear to apply to styling of standard lightning components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get Display density information using `Salesforce User Interface API`. This [Link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_api_ui_density.htm) will help you. I don't think you can directly access Salesforce UI-API from Lightning controller, but you can use `Apex` class to achieve this.

Comment: The link you provided indicates performing a GET request to /ui-api/themes/active.  However, the documentation indicates this is the org's active theme.  How do you get the individual user's display density?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to call the REST API from Javascript through Apex. Theoretically it should be possible: UserInfo.getSessionId() gives a session id. But if you try to use that, by passing it to Apex to call the REST API, then all you get is: This session is not valid for use with the REST API

Comment: While it is not possible to pass a session id from Javascript to Apex, you can use a new session Id in the Apex code (via logging in, yes, you actually have to do that). But this turns out to be no use at all, because the new (Apex) session will always have the default density, namely ViewOne, as it is in no way connected to the Javascript session.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Is there any specific reason you want to detect display density in the LWC?, have you tried [Variable Density Classes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/#Variable-Density-Classes)  from SLDS ?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes I have looked at those. I am using slds-p-top_large and slds-p-bottom_large for my own LWC, but switching between Comfy and Compact does not make the paddings small enough when compared to standard components. I have to switch to slds-p-top_small and slds-p-bottom_small to make my LWC look good in Compact density.

Comment: try `slds-var-p-top_large` and `slds-var-p-bottom_large`. @SanderdeJong

Comment: @rahulgawale I missed the "-var-" part in those names. I am going to give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @rahulgawale Perfect! That does the job for me! Sorry that I can't award you the bonus, but you solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @SanderdeJong No problem I have added my answer so that it will be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your custom components to be responsive to the Display Density use the variable density slds classes.

For example variable classes for padding

```
slds-var-p-top_large
slds-var-p-bottom_large
```

Similarly for margin

```
slds-var-m-around_xxx-small
slds-var-m-around_small
```

[Variable Density Classes Margin](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/#Variable-Density-Classes) 
[Variable Density Classes Padding](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/#Variable-Density-Classes)

Comment: Hi @Rahul struggling to find out how to use there vars to respect a form's density setting. I have a record-edit-form with a mix of standard lightning-input-field and custom components wrapping input fields and I don't get how to make sure my custom ones swap between stacked and horizontal as screen gets smaller/bigger. Can I achieve that with these vars?

Comment: @alesremta use lightning layout inside the record edit form to make it responsive

Answer (score 3):

If you have some lightning-output-field's inside a lightning-record-view-form or lightning-record-edit-form, you can look for the slds-form-element_horizontal or _stacked class in the DOM using the renderedCallback() method.

For example, in your .js:

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

export default class lwcComponent extends LightningElement {

   @track displayCSS;
   hasRendered = false;

   renderedCallback()
   {
     if(! this.hasRendered)  // only render once
     {
        const elemsByClassName = this.template.querySelectorAll('.slds-form-element_horizontal');   //check if other elements are rendered comfy or cozy
        if (elemsByClassName.length>0)
        {
            this.displayCSS='slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal';
        } else {
            this.displayCSS='slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked';
        }
        this.hasRenderd = true;
    }
  }

  get myCustomUrl()
  {
      // add logic here to make this dynamic
      return 'myCustomUrl';
  }

  get myCustomName()
  {
      // add logic here to make this dynamic
      return 'myCustomName';
  }

}
```

Then display a custom built field, in this case a URL, using the dynamically set css and variables:

```
   <div class={displayCSS}>
       <span class="slds-form-element__label">My Label</span>
       <lightning-helptext content="My Custom Help Text"></lightning-helptext>
       <div class="slds-form-element__control"><lightning-formatted-url class="slds-form-element__static" value={myCustomUrl} label={myCustomName}></lightning-formatted-url></div>
   </div>
```

This works well if you have a mixture of standard fields and custom built fields and want them all to respect the user selected Display Density.

Mike

Comment: I thought this worked for me, as I was testing in Compact mode. Then I turned to Comfy and still the Javascript thought the UI was in Compact :-(

Comment: @SanderdeJong - This worked for me as long as I had one lightning-output-field in the LWC.  The lightning-output-field gets rendered as either comfy or compact, and then the above code renders the custom built field correctly.

Comment: I see. My LWC has no lightning-output-field. I thought of making a hidden one, but then I guess it can't be found by the query selector.

Comment: @SanderdeJong - You might investigate the difference between visibility vs display. In css, visibility: hidden still takes up space, but display: none does not.  Not sure if my code would pick up the lightning-output-field that has visibility:hidden.